# fscanf() error on this text file?

Tags: c, file, text, stream, stdin

test.txt:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
The color of the car is blue
```

code:

```
FILE *fp;
char var[30];
int result

if( (fp = fopen( "test.txt", "r")) == NULL)  //open for read
    printf("ERROR");


result = fscanf( fp, "The color of the car is %s", &var);
```

After this executes:

> opens file (not NULL and was able to execute an append when testing)
>   result = 0  //zero- in the case of a matching failure....?
>   errno = 0;
>   and var is garbage.

I was expecting fscanf() to match "blue".

How should I correctly get blue into var?
Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fscanf doesn't work like this. It doesn't look around nor scan the string for stuff to match. You have to supply a string *exactly* matching the format specifier. So you could do stuff like

```
result = fscanf(fp, "aaaaaaaaaaaaa\nbbbbbbbbbbb\ncccccccccc\nThe color of the car is %s", &var);
```

to achieve what you want.

Comment: what would be the most efficient way to scan and then match "blue". Can I set the cursor to the last line and then run this fscanf() ?

Comment: ok thanks, the book I'm referencing states fscanf() : "format is a text string that indicates the place and format of the data to be read from the stream." Since it said "place" I assumed the function was doing this.

Comment: @Tommy but if the format string has to indicate the place, then it's exactly what it's doing. Because then scanf won't look for any other place trying to match a string. If it's there, it matches. If it isn't, it doesn't match.

Answer (score 4):

How about using `fgets` instead:

```
char *search = "The color of the..";
char *p;
while (fgets(var, SIZE, stdin)) {
    /* Does it have what we want ? */
    if ((p = strstr(var, search)))
        break;
}

if (p)
    p += strlen(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a bug where you are passing in the pointer to an array of char into `fscanf`, when you should be passing in a pointer to char. It so happens that the address of an array equals the address of the first element of an array, so it works on accident. But, the wrong type is being passed in.

In addition, you want to find the line which provides you with the match, and you seem to want to store `"blue"` into `var`. To do this, you should test to see if a line of input matches your scan pattern. You can use `fgets` to read a line, and use `sscanf` to scan the line.

```
while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp) != 0) {
    result = sscanf(buf, "The color of the car is %s", var);
    if (result == 1) break;
}
```

`sscanf` will return how many directives it successfully scanned. In this case, there is the one `%s` directive.

Doing it this way prevents a scanning error from "jamming" your input parsing. That is, if `fscanf` returns an error, it will fail to move past the input that caused the error until you call `clearerr()`.

Comment: good catch, I originally had an integer here but should have changed it.

Comment: what size does buf depend on for this to work, does it have to be the length of each line?

Comment: @Tommy: It should be long enough to capture the longest line you read in, plus two (one for newline, one for '\0' terminator). Or, you write your own `getline` routine that can grow the buffer as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You have another bug here in that if test.txt doesn't exist, your code will go ahead and use fscanf anyway, making your check useless. This would almost certainly cause the program to crash.

Answer (score 1):

Use regex

```
char p[100];
char q[100];
char r[100];
fscanf(fp, "%[^\n]\n%[^\n]\n%[^\n]\nThe color of the car is %s",p,q,r, &var);
```

Modify it according to your requirement. I know this is not your actual string.

Comment: is this more efficient that using the functions in cnicutar's answer?

Comment: strstr is expensive function. fscanf is also expensive, but here you are doing multiple things in single fscanf. Has this been divided into multiple fscanf, it would have been expenisve too.